# Error: "ld returned 1 exit status" when building DLL file in C++

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I'm just learning how to make a DLL in C++ and I made a DLL and when I try to compile my main Cpp file it gives this error:

```
id.exe: cannot find -lfactorial
collect2.exe: error: id returned 1 exit status
```

This is the file that my DLL was built with:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) long int factorial(int);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
long int factorial( int n ){
    if( n > 1 )
        return n * factorial( n - 1 );
    else return 1;
}
```

I compiled it with this command:
`g++ factorial.cpp -o factorial.dll -shared`
This is the original code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) long int factorial(int);
int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter n: ";
    cin>>n;
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Factorial "<<n<<" = "<<factorial(n);
    return 0;
}
```

And I compiled the original code with this command:
`g++ main.cpp -o app.exe -lfactorial`
Thank you for telling me where the problem is

Comment: are you using MinGW?

Comment: hi , no my compiler is TDM in "Embarcadero Dev-C++"

Comment: *-lfactorial.dll*?

Comment: hi -lfactorial @CristiFati

Comment: No, I was making a suggestion: `g++ main.cpp -o app.exe -lfactorial.dll`. Also in the error message it's *ld* not *id*.